# scrapy recursive link crawler with login - help me improve

Tags: recursion, scrapy

To best of my current knowledge I have written a little web spider/crawler that is able to crawl recursively with a variable nesting depth is also capable of doing an optional POST/GET pre-login before crawling (if required).

As I am a complete beginner, I would like to get some feedback, improvements or whatever your throw at this.

I am only adding the `parser` function here. The whole source can be viewed at github: https://github.com/cytopia/crawlpy

What I really want to make sure is that the recursion in combination with `yield` is as efficient as possible and that I am also doing it in the right way.

Any comments on that and the coding style a very much welcome.

```
def parse(self, response):
    """
    Scrapy parse callback
    """

    # Get current nesting level
    if response.meta.has_key('depth'):
        curr_depth = response.meta['depth']
    else:
        curr_depth = 1


    # Only crawl the current page if we hit a HTTP-200
    if response.status == 200:
        hxs = Selector(response)
        links = hxs.xpath("//a/@href").extract()

        # We stored already crawled links in this list
        crawled_links = []

        # Pattern to check proper link
        linkPattern  = re.compile("^(?:http|https):\/\/(?:[\w\.\-\+]+:{0,1}[\w\.\-\+]*@)?(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$")

        for link in links:

            # Link could be a relative url from response.url
            # such as link: '../test', respo.url: http://dom.tld/foo/bar
            if link.find('../') == 0:
                link = response.url + '/' + link
            # Prepend BASE URL if it does not have it
            elif 'http://' not in link and 'https://' not in link:
                link = self.base_url + link


            # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
            if (link
                    and linkPattern.match(link)
                    and link.find(self.base_url) == 0):
                    #and link not in crawled_links
                    #and link not in uniques):

                # Check if this url already exists
                re_exists = re.compile('^' + link + '$')
                exists = False
                for i in self.uniques:
                    if re_exists.match(i):
                        exists = True
                        break

                if not exists:
                    # Store the shit
                    crawled_links.append(link)
                    self.uniques.append(link)

                    # Do we recurse?
                    if curr_depth < self.depth:
                        request = Request(link, self.parse)
                        # Add meta-data about the current recursion depth
                        request.meta['depth'] = curr_depth + 1
                        yield request
                    else:
                        # Nesting level too deep
                        pass
            else:
                # Link not in condition
                pass


        #
        # Final return (yield) to user
        #
        for url in crawled_links:
            #print "FINAL FINAL FINAL URL: " + response.url
            item = CrawlpyItem()
            item['url'] = url
            item['depth'] = curr_depth

            yield item
        #print "FINAL FINAL FINAL URL: " + response.url
        #item = CrawlpyItem()
        #item['url'] = response.url
        #yield item
    else:
        # NOT HTTP 200
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole code could be shortened to something like:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
def parse(self, response):
    # Get current nesting level
    curr_depth = response.meta.get('depth',1)
    item = CrawlpyItem()  # could also just be `item = dict()`
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['depth'] = curr_depth
    yield item

    links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
        yield Request(link.url, meta={'depth': curr_depth+1})
```

If I understand correctly what you want to do here is broad crawl all urls, yield depth and url as items right?

Scrapy already has dupe filter enabled by default, so you don't need to do that logic yourself. Also your `parse()` method will never receive anything but response 200 so that check is useless.

Edit: rework to avoid dupes.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. Looks much cleaner. There are however two problems with that. I get lot's of duplicate links (when saving to json for example) and also links outside my allowed domains are stored. Anything I am overlooking?

Comment: @cytopia good catch! There's was a huge flaw in the spider that would return urls _before_ downloading them, so scrapy dupe filters and allowed_domain filters were never actually used. I've edited the question with a fix!

Comment: Granitosaurus Thanks for the edit. Some remarks:
`item['url'] = link.url`: Now `link` is being used before defined in the `for` loop. Or do you mean `response.url`? Also, could you please explain, why you have defaulted `depth` to zero instead of 1?

Comment: Yeah it should be response.url and regarding depth starting at zero it doesn't really matter but it kinda makes sense, doesn't it? As long as you increment the meta value you'll get the correct data.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, unfortunately my reputation does not allow me to vote this up. so (Y)